# Is he "making a play" for her or is he "making a pass" at her?

Tags: differences, meaning-in-context

> - to make a play for someone - to attempt to attract the romantic interest of someone.
> - to make a pass at someone - to  make a romantic advance at someone.

To a non-native speaker, the difference seems to be "the subtlety of one's action" in "make a play for" whereas, in the second case, "to make a pass" would imply a more active or aggressive approach.  Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Collins Dict.  the two expressions are quite close in meaning, but *make a play for someone* actually may suggest a more romantic involvement than *make a pass at someone*.

[Make a pass at someone](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/make-a-pass-at-someone):

> - make advances to, proposition, hit on (US & Canadian, slang), come on to (informal), *make a play for* (informal), make an approach to, make sexual overtures to.

- Was he just being friendly, or was he making a pass at her?
- It seems as if those boys can't think of much more than fast cars and making passes at girls.
- In the movie, she makes a play for her best friend's husband.
- If I wasn't happily married, I might make a play for him myself.

Source: www.collinsdictionary.com

Comment: From your examples one might infer that women would tend to "make a play for someone" whereas men would more likely make a pass at women.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @user463240 - my examples are sentences I found in the web. Make a pass at is more often associated with boys/men, but not only to them I guess :))

Answer (score 3):

I would consider *making a play* to involve any set of actions that have as goal to obtain the interest or favors of someone. Those actions need not involve any direct interaction with that person.  They might involve preparation, contrivance of circumstances or events, and so on. Of course ultimately there would presumably involve some direct contact/interaction, but not all of the actions making up the "play" need involve the other person directly. The "play" can be involved, complex, and long, but it need not be. (It could amount to nothing more than making a pass - but it need not.)

*Making a pass* is direct, short, and typically obvious. It involves some direct interaction, typically grabbing the attention of the other person in one form or another.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider *"making a pass"* to be a brief, one-time, event and *"making a play"* to be longer-term than a 1-5 minute encounter.